# jQuery targeting element inside a div with only unique data-field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the following HTML of which I have no control:

```
<div class="form-wrap">
      <div class='input-wrap' data-field='start-set'>
             <input type='radio' name='participant[0][start-set][value]' value='Information centre' class='participant-form--input-radio'/>
             <span>Information centre</span>

             <input type='radio' name='participant[0][start-set][value]' value='Terminal' class='participant-form--input-radio'/>
             <span>Terminal<span>
     </div>
     <div class='input-wrap' data-field='delivery'>
         ...
     </div>
</div>
```

And this might be repeated multiple times in the same page, for different participants.

What needs to be done is to capture the `radio input` change and if the radio value is 'terminal', to display the sibling div with `data-field='delivery'`.

I am really bad at front end, so would appreciate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tree [traversal#next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method

```
$("input[type='radio'].participant-form--input-radio").on('change', function() {

    var currentRadio = $(this);
    if (currentRadio.val() == "terminal") {

        currentRadio.parent().next().show();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to bind a change event to your  radio button, I've used the *name starts with ...* selector.

```
$('input[name^=participant]').on('change', function() {
```

Alternatives are:

```
$('input:radio') /* all radiobuttons */
$('.form-wrap input:radio') /* all radiobuttons inside .form-wrap */
$('.participant-form--input-radio') /* class selector */
```

After that we need to find the element we want to show and hide. I prefer to travel up the tree to the elements parent and the find the child we are looking for

```
$(this).closest('.form-wrap').find('[data-field="delivery"]')
```

Then I use `toggle(statement)` to either hide or show it. The statement in this case will be "is the value 'Terminal'"

```
.toggle( $(this).val() == 'Terminal' )
```

All together, it looks like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name^=participant]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('.form-wrap').find('[data-field="delivery"]').toggle( $(this).val() == 'Terminal' );
  });
});
```

```css
[data-field="delivery"] { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrap">
  <div class='input-wrap' data-field='start-set'>
    <input type='radio' name='participant[0][start-set][value]' value='Information centre' class='participant-form--input-radio' />
    <span>Information centre</span>

    <input type='radio' name='participant[0][start-set][value]' value='Terminal' class='participant-form--input-radio' />
    <span>Terminal</span>
  </div>
  <div class='input-wrap' data-field='delivery'>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Terminal') {
    $(this).parents('.input-wrap').next('[data-field=delivery]').show();
  } else {
    $(this).parents('.input-wrap').next('[data-field=delivery]').hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrap">
  <div class='input-wrap' data-field='start-set'>
    <input type='radio' name='participant[0][start-set][value]' value='Information centre' class='participant-form--input-radio' />
    <span>Information centre</span>

    <input type='radio' name='participant[0][start-set][value]' value='Terminal' class='participant-form--input-radio' />
    <span>Terminal<span>
     </div>
     <div class='input-wrap' data-field='delivery' style="display:none;">
         ... 
     </div>
</div>
```